# match if column is part of a value in Where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question:

I am trying to match a value (url) against a value in dbtable, column UrlPart.

Let's say a column UrlPart in a row has the value 'id=12345'.

Now I have a query:

```
select * from products
where UrlPart [is part of] 
'http://www.domain.com/category/?id=12345&referrer=www.google.com&etcetera'
```

I would like to see the match [id=12345 [is part of] 'http://www.domain.com/category/?id=12345& as true, so it will return the product row.

Of course [Is part of] doesn't exist, but what I want to know if it is possible to match the value in the column against the expression of the url which will change for each request.
Like a normal where statement but then reveresed.

Is something like this possible with `SQL 2008 Express Edition` ?

[UPDATE]

I have tested the like '%' + UrlPart '%' and the CharIndex and according to MS SQL's exectution plan, they are identical. Seems that SQL does the same thing underwater, so both options are good.

I would think that CharIndex might be a bit more raw then like (like might be converted) so I go for that one now.

Thank you all.

Comment: so you just change the id in the url in your query?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from products 
where 'http://www.domain.com/category/?id=12345&referrer=www.google.com&etcetera'  
      like '%'+UrlPart+'%'
```

Comment: Okay, I tried like and I did %UrlPart% of which I knew it wouldn't work, but I did not know that you could concat the % around it. I will now check which version is faster, Like or CharIndex. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from products
where 'http://www.domain.com/category/?id=12345&referrer=www.google.com&etcetera' like '%' + UrlPart + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `charindex` :

```
select * from products
where charindex('http://www.domain.com...',urlPart)<>0
```

Comment: yes, I knocked my head against the wall to clear it up and tought of a string compare, which is CharIndex and it works. But thanks for your idea!